# Using C, While initializing an array of structs, it seems like the first column, and the last column are overlooping

Tags: c, arrays, struct

When main runs, I've been getting this output. The first columns being somehow confused with the last one, even though it's specifically initialized.

0   0   0   0   0   0   4   3  13   3   3   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   5   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0  18   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0  17   0   0   0
   0   0   4   0   2   0   7  12  19  12   3   0   8   0   2   0   0
   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0
   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   2
   2   0   0   0  11   0   0   0   5   0   0   0  11   0   0   0   1
   1   7   7   7  20   7   7   7  14   7   7   7  20   7   7   7   1
   1   0   0   0  11   0   0   0   5   0   0   0  11   0   0   0   1
   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0
   0   0   6   0   4   0   7  12  19  12   3   0   6   0   8   0   0
   0   0   0  15   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0  16   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   5   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   7   7   7   8   0   0   0   0   0   0

motion.h

```
struct square{
  int directions;
  int isRobotHere;
  int isMultipleDirections;
  int printable;
};
typedef struct square Square;

struct robot{
  int robotx;
  int roboty;
  int robotz;
  int destinationx;
  int destinationy;
  int destinationz;
};
typedef struct robot Robot;
enum direction{North, NorthWest, West, SouthWest, South, SouthEast, East, NorthEast};
Square firstfloor[16][16];
Square secondfloor[16][16];
void printbothfloors();
void initializeArrays();
```

initializeArrays.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "motion.h"
void initializeArrays(){
firstfloor[6][0].directions=5;
firstfloor[7][0].directions=5;
firstfloor[8][0].directions=14;
firstfloor[9][0].directions=5;
firstfloor[10][0].directions=6;
firstfloor[11][1].directions=6;
firstfloor[12][2].directions=6;
firstfloor[13][3].directions=15;
firstfloor[14][4].directions=6;
firstfloor[15][5].directions=6;
firstfloor[16][6].directions=7;
firstfloor[16][7].directions=7;
firstfloor[16][8].directions=7;
firstfloor[16][9].directions=7;
firstfloor[16][10].directions=8;
firstfloor[15][11].directions=8;
firstfloor[14][12].directions=8;
firstfloor[13][13].directions=16;
firstfloor[12][14].directions=8;
firstfloor[11][15].directions=8;
firstfloor[10][16].directions=1;
firstfloor[9][16].directions=1;
firstfloor[8][16].directions=1;
firstfloor[7][16].directions=1;
firstfloor[6][16].directions=2;
firstfloor[5][15].directions=2;
firstfloor[4][14].directions=2;
firstfloor[3][13].directions=17;
firstfloor[2][12].directions=2;
firstfloor[1][11].directions=2;
firstfloor[0][10].directions=3;
firstfloor[0][9].directions=3;
firstfloor[0][8].directions=13;
firstfloor[0][7].directions=3;
firstfloor[0][6].directions=4;
firstfloor[1][5].directions=4;
firstfloor[2][4].directions=4;
firstfloor[3][3].directions=18;
firstfloor[4][2].directions=4;
firstfloor[5][1].directions=4;
firstfloor[1][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[2][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[3][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[4][8].directions=19;
firstfloor[5][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[6][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[7][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[8][8].directions=14;
firstfloor[9][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[10][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[11][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[12][8].directions=19;
firstfloor[13][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[14][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[15][8].directions=5;
firstfloor[8][1].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][2].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][3].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][4].directions=20;
firstfloor[8][5].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][6].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][7].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][9].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][10].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][11].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][12].directions=20;
firstfloor[8][13].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][14].directions=7;
firstfloor[8][15].directions=7;
firstfloor[7][4].directions=11;
firstfloor[9][4].directions=11;
firstfloor[4][7].directions=12;
firstfloor[4][9].directions=12;
firstfloor[12][7].directions=12;
firstfloor[12][9].directions=12;
firstfloor[7][12].directions=11;
firstfloor[9][12].directions=11;
firstfloor[4][4].directions=2;
firstfloor[4][6].directions=7;
firstfloor[4][10].directions=3;
firstfloor[4][12].directions=8;
firstfloor[6][4].directions=5;
firstfloor[6][12].directions=5;  
 firstfloor[10][4].directions=1;
firstfloor[10][12].directions=1;
firstfloor[12][4].directions=4;
firstfloor[12][6].directions=7;
firstfloor[12][10].directions=3;
firstfloor[12][12].directions=6;
firstfloor[11][0].directions=0;
firstfloor[5][16].directions=0;
}
```

printbothfloors.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "motion.h"
void printbothfloors(){
  //  printf("printfloor is running");
  int upper, lower, i, j;
  printf("%4d %4d %4d %4d %4d", firstfloor[6][0].directions, firstfloor[7][0].directions, firstfloor[8][0].directions, firstfloor[9][0].directions, firstfloor[10][0].directions);
  printf("%4d %4d %4d %4d %4d", firstfloor[6][16].directions, firstfloor[7][16].directions, firstfloor[8][16].directions, firstfloor[9][16].directions, firstfloor[10][16].directions);


  printf("FIRST FLOOR");
  printf("\n-");
  /* The next for loop prints out the upper edge */
  for (upper = 0; upper < 18; upper++){
    printf("----");
  }
  printf("\n");

  /*The next for loop prints out the floor, every element is 4 digits wide */
  for (i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
    printf("|");
    for(j = 0; j <= 16; j++){
      printf("%4d", firstfloor[i][j].directions);
    }
    printf("   |\n");
  }
  /* The next for loop prints out the lower edge */
  for (lower = 0; lower < 18; lower++){
    printf("----");
  }
  printf("-\n");
  /*
  printf("SECOND FLOOR");
  //  printf("printfloor is running");
  printf("\n-----");
  // The next for loop prints out the upper edge 
  for (upper = 0; upper < 17; upper++){
    printf("----");
  }
  printf("\n");

  //The next for loop prints out the floor, every element is 4 digits wide 
  for (i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
    printf("|");
    for(j = 0; j <= 16; j++){
      printf("%4d", secondfloor[i][j].directions);
    }
    printf("   |\n");
  }
  // The next for loop prints out the lower edge 
  for (lower = 0; lower < 17; lower++){
    printf("----");
  }
  printf("-----\n");
*/
}
```

prog2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "motion.h"
//#include "printbothfloors.h"
int main(){
  int row = 0;
  int column = 0;
  initializeArrays();   
// printbothfloors();
/*
  for (row=0; row < 17; row++){
    for (column=0; column < 17; column++){

      // firstfloor[row][column].directions=0;
      // secondfloor[row][column].directions=5;
      //firstfloor[i][j].isRobotHere=0;
      //secondfloor[i][j].isRobotHere=0;
       //firstfloor[i][j].isMultipleDirections=0;
       //secondfloor[i][j].isMultipleDirections=0;

    }
  }

 firstfloor[6][0].directions=5;
 firstfloor[7][0].directions=5;
 firstfloor[8][0].directions=14;
 firstfloor[9][0].directions=5;
 firstfloor[10][0].directions=6;
 firstfloor[11][1].directions=6;
 firstfloor[12][2].directions=6;
 firstfloor[13][3].directions=15;
 firstfloor[14][4].directions=6;
 firstfloor[15][5].directions=6;
 firstfloor[16][6].directions=7;
 firstfloor[16][7].directions=7;
 firstfloor[16][8].directions=7;
 firstfloor[16][9].directions=7;
 firstfloor[16][10].directions=8;
 firstfloor[15][11].directions=8;
 firstfloor[14][12].directions=8;
 firstfloor[13][13].directions=16;
 firstfloor[12][14].directions=8;
 firstfloor[11][15].directions=8;
 firstfloor[10][16].directions=1;
 firstfloor[9][16].directions=1;
 firstfloor[8][16].directions=1;
 firstfloor[7][16].directions=1;
 firstfloor[6][16].directions=2;
 firstfloor[5][15].directions=2;
 firstfloor[4][14].directions=2;
 firstfloor[3][13].directions=17;
 firstfloor[2][12].directions=2;
 firstfloor[1][11].directions=2;
 firstfloor[0][10].directions=3;
 firstfloor[0][9].directions=3;
 firstfloor[0][8].directions=13;
 firstfloor[0][7].directions=3;
 firstfloor[0][6].directions=4;
 firstfloor[1][5].directions=4;
 firstfloor[2][4].directions=4;
 firstfloor[3][3].directions=18;
 firstfloor[4][2].directions=4;
 firstfloor[5][1].directions=4;
 firstfloor[1][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[2][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[3][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[4][8].directions=19;
   firstfloor[5][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[6][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[7][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[8][8].directions=14;
   firstfloor[9][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[10][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[11][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[12][8].directions=19;
   firstfloor[13][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[14][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[15][8].directions=5;
   firstfloor[8][1].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][2].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][3].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][4].directions=20;
   firstfloor[8][5].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][6].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][7].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][9].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][10].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][11].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][12].directions=20;
   firstfloor[8][13].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][14].directions=7;
   firstfloor[8][15].directions=7;
   firstfloor[7][4].directions=11;
   firstfloor[9][4].directions=11;
   firstfloor[4][7].directions=12;
   firstfloor[4][9].directions=12;
   firstfloor[12][7].directions=12;
   firstfloor[12][9].directions=12;
   firstfloor[7][12].directions=11;
   firstfloor[9][12].directions=11;
   firstfloor[4][4].directions=2;
   firstfloor[4][6].directions=7;
   firstfloor[4][10].directions=3;
   firstfloor[4][12].directions=8;
   firstfloor[6][4].directions=5;
   firstfloor[6][12].directions=5;
   firstfloor[10][4].directions=1;
   firstfloor[10][12].directions=1;
   firstfloor[12][4].directions=4;
   firstfloor[12][6].directions=7;
   firstfloor[12][10].directions=3;
   firstfloor[12][12].directions=6;
   firstfloor[11][0].directions=0;
   firstfloor[5][16].directions=0;
*/
   // for (i = 0; i < 17; i++){
   // firstfloor
   // printbothfloors();
   // pbf_entrypoints();
/*
row = 0;
column = 0;
while (i < 17){
  firstfloor[i][8] = 1;
  secondfloor[i][8] = 1;
  firstfloor[8][i] = 1;
  secondfloor[8][i] = 1;
  i++;
 }
*/
 printf("Function got here");
 printbothfloors();

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not use the index `16` if your array is 16 elements long.

Answer (score 2):

Valid indices for `Type arr[N]` are between `0` and `N-1`.

This goes for any `Type` and for any number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes in C start at 0, so if you declare an array to have 16 elements, valid indexes start from 0 and end at 15.

16 boxes, numbered 0 to 15:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Accessing an element outside of this range (e.g. by using the index -1 or 16) invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Both the first answers are correct, I'll add some examples from your code.

```
firstfloor[6][16].directions
```

firstfloor[x][y], has been initialized as firstfloor[16][16] meaning the values x and y can can from 0 to 15. The numbering system is 0 based, a hang-over from Java's C language ancestry. 0-15 covers 16 elements.

```
/*The next for loop prints out the floor, every element is 4 digits wide */
for (i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
  printf("|");
  for(j = 0; j <= 16; j++){
    printf("%4d", firstfloor[i][j].directions);
  }
  printf("   |\n");
}
```

The two for loops, start correctly at i = 0 and should only continue while i < 16 or if you prefer i <= 15.

At the moment I'm personally jumping between Java, C and Python, so someone might correct me in this, but calling firstfloor[6][16] if it does not generate an array out-of-bounds error, will give you the same result as firstfloor[7][0]. This might explain why you are observing the first columns being confused with the last.

Good luck :-)